# xbacklight doesn't work Linux Mint i3

Tags: i3, brightness

Hello follow Linux users,

I am currently setting up i3 and I want to configure the brightness buttons. I want to use xbacklight for this but it doesn't work. If I enter xbacklight into the terminal and hit enter no message is shown. The only xbacklight command which prints anything to the terminal is xbacklight -h. xbacklight -get doesn't print anything and xbacklight -set doesn't change the brightness.

I was able to change the brightness in Cinnamon desktop and everything worked there.

I have a Dell XPS 15 with an nvidia graphics card and an intel core i7

Comment: Anything on `dmesg` or `journalctl`?

Comment: My `xbacklight` broke a few months ago, I'm on Debian Stretch, `i3`.